# Are Java Transactions Propagated to MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, stored-procedures, transactions

[I have been getting conflicting information on the web, hence asking a specific question.]

My Java App uses Declarative Spring Transactions (with Hibernate ORM).

If my application calls a MySQL Stored Procedure from Java (DAO) layer, is my transaction propagated?

Any information will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are not java transactions. Declarative transactions just send a `BEGIN TRNANSACTION` (or whatever the syntax for db vendor is). So - yes, it will be within that transaction.

(well, spring's declarative trnasactions do a couple more things, like creating/closing a hibernate session and populating a few threadlocal resource, but with regard to the transactions itself, it's a simple begin transaction)